# ASP.net URL rewriting conflicts with image folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have the rules:

```
<rewrite url="~/construct2" to="~/construct2.aspx" processing="stop"/>
<rewrite url="~/construct" to="~/Handlers/PermRedirect.ashx?URL=construct2" processing="stop"/>
```

Along with many many more.

When I attempt to visit:

http://84.45.57.142/images/construct2-screenshot.jpg

It seems to activate these rules and redirect you to construct2.aspx.  Does anyone know why?  I thought `~/construct` would only match `root directory/construct` not `any directory/construct*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<rewrite url="~/construct2$" to="~/construct2.aspx" processing="stop"/>
```

Comment: @Tom Gullen - this means end of line in Regex.